# C Programming: Read from file and print on screen

Tags: c, struct, structure

I am trying to read a file test.txt via fscanf and store it in a array of struct. I have posted the code that I have tried. Looks like problem here is with **load function**

This is what I have in **test.txt:**

```
205,11.20,John Snow
336,23.40,Winter is coming
220,34.20,You know nothing
```

load function uses loadinput function to read test.txt file into the “item” array and sets the target of the **“NoPtr”** to the number of Items read from the file (which in this case should be 3).

After reading the file, I am also trying to print it on screen, but it won't work. Nothing is displayed at all.

This program compiles. What is it that I am doing wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Item {
   double value;
   int unit;
   char name[50];
};

int load(struct Item* item, char Name[], int* NoPtr);
int loadinput(struct Item* item, FILE* data);
void display(struct Item item, int variableA);

int main(void) 
{
    struct Item FIN[3];
   int i, n;
   load(FIN, "test.txt", &n);
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
   {
      display(FIN[i],0);
   }
return 0;
}


int load(struct Item* item, char Name[], int* NoPtr)
{
    struct Item ARR[3];
    int flagcheck;
    FILE* fl;
    fl =  fopen("Name[]", "r");
    while (fl)
    {
        flagcheck = loadinput(&ARR, fl);
        if (flagcheck < 0)
        {
            fclose(fl);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            *NoPtr++;
        }
    fclose(fl);
    }
return 0;
}

int loadinput(struct Item* item, FILE* data)
{
    int ret = fscanf(data, "%d,%lf,", &item->unit, &item->value);
    if (ret != 2) {
            return -1;
    }
    fgets(item->name, sizeof item->name, data);
    item->name[strlen(item->name)-1] = '\0';
    return 0;
}

void display(struct Item item, int variableA)
{
printf("|%3d |%12.2lf| %20s |***\n", item.unit, item.value, item.name);
return;
}
```

Comment: `fopen("Name[]", "r");` and then just assume it worked with no error checking? `Name[]` is a pretty odd filename...

Comment: do you mean `fopen(Name, "r");` ?

Comment: `item->name[strlen(item->name)-1]` Terminating a string by using `strlen` on the string you are trying to terminate?

Comment: @John3136 I wanted to pass file name as a parameter from load(FIN, "test.txt", &n);

Comment: @john It's clear that you want to do that. But can you see that you are not doing that? Always check the return value of important API calls like `fopen`.

Comment: @John That is not what you have done. You are opening "Name[]" which probably doesn't exist, but you read from it anyway. That's a pretty big problem...

Comment: `*NoPtr++;` --> `++*NoPtr;` or `(*NoPtr)++;`

Comment: @John3136: I changed it to just Name as  user bansi mentioned :)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I tried that before and all I got was "*** glibc detected *** a.out: double free or corruption (top): 0x0804b008 ***
"

Comment: `struct Item ARR[3];` --> `*NoPtr = 0;`...`flagcheck = loadinput(&ARR, fl);` --> `flagcheck = loadinput(&item[*NoPtr], fl);`.. `fclose(fl);
    }` --> `} fclose(fl);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: I even tried that. I get  "*** glibc detected *** a.out: double free or corruption (top): 0x0804b008 ***

Comment: see [fix demo](http://ideone.com/lfmnJk)

Comment: AH! sorry `fclose(fl); break;` --> `break;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY You are a life saver man! Wow! I never thought about this.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Ty for your help

Comment: `fclose(fl); }` --> `}` more better.

Answer (score 0):

see fix demo – BLUEPIXY

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Item {
    double value;
    int unit;
    char name[50];
};

int load(struct Item* item, char Name[], int* NoPtr);
int loadinput(struct Item* item, FILE* data);
void display(struct Item item, int variableA);

int main(void) {
    struct Item FIN[3];
    int i, n;
    load(FIN, "test.txt", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        display(FIN[i],0);
    }
    return 0;
}

int load(struct Item* item, char Name[], int* NoPtr){
    *NoPtr = 0;
    int flagcheck;
    FILE* fl;
    fl =  stdin;//fopen(Name, "r");//for ideone
    while (fl){
        flagcheck = loadinput(&item[*NoPtr], fl);
        if (flagcheck < 0){
            fclose(fl);
            break;
        } else {
            ++*NoPtr;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int loadinput(struct Item* item, FILE* data){
    int ret = fscanf(data, "%d,%lf,", &item->unit, &item->value);
    if (ret != 2) {
        return -1;
    }
    fgets(item->name, sizeof item->name, data);
    item->name[strlen(item->name)-1] = '\0';
    return 0;
}

void display(struct Item item, int variableA){
    printf("|%3d |%12.2lf| %20s |***\n", item.unit, item.value, item.name);
    return;
}
```